# Magento backup linking to Old URL

Tags: magento-1.9

I've copied over the contents of the old file structure to the new one. I.E;

> www/SHOP1 to www/newstore/SHOP2

Copied the current database to a new database and edited `core_config_data` to point to the new URL. Then I deleted everything in `/var/cache` and `/var/session`.

When I view the new URL it loads for a second then links to the old URL still. The new URL is on the same server (same FTP details, folder is located inside main DIR where the old store is)

Anything else I have to edit?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer incase anyone else has the same problem.

I used the magento-cleanup.php utility which seemed to solve everything. No idea what the problem was. Here it is incase you want to create your own;

```
<?php

## Function to set file permissions to 0644 and folder permissions to 0755

function AllDirChmod( $dir = "./", $dirModes = 0755, $fileModes = 0644 ){
   $d = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $dir );
   foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $d, 1 ) as $path ){
      if( $path->isDir() ) chmod( $path, $dirModes );
      else if( is_file( $path ) ) chmod( $path, $fileModes );
  }
}

## Function to clean out the contents of specified directory

function cleandir($dir) {

    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && is_file($dir.'/'.$file)) {
                if (unlink($dir.'/'.$file)) { }
                else { echo $dir . '/' . $file . ' (file) NOT deleted!<br />'; }
            }
            else if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)) {
                cleandir($dir.'/'.$file);
                if (rmdir($dir.'/'.$file)) { }
                else { echo $dir . '/' . $file . ' (directory) NOT deleted!<br />'; }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }

}

function isDirEmpty($dir){
     return (($files = @scandir($dir)) && count($files) <= 2);
}

echo "----------------------- CLEANUP START -------------------------<br/>";
$start = (float) array_sum(explode(' ',microtime()));
echo "<br/>*************** SETTING PERMISSIONS ***************<br/>";
echo "Setting all folder permissions to 755<br/>";
echo "Setting all file permissions to 644<br/>";
AllDirChmod( "." );
echo "Setting pear permissions to 550<br/>";
chmod("pear", 550);

echo "<br/>****************** CLEARING CACHE ******************<br/>";

if (file_exists("var/cache")) {
    echo "Clearing var/cache<br/>";
    cleandir("var/cache");
}

if (file_exists("var/session")) {
    echo "Clearing var/session<br/>";
    cleandir("var/session");
}

if (file_exists("var/minifycache")) {
    echo "Clearing var/minifycache<br/>";
    cleandir("var/minifycache");
}

if (file_exists("downloader/pearlib/cache")) {
    echo "Clearing downloader/pearlib/cache<br/>";
    cleandir("downloader/pearlib/cache");
}

if (file_exists("downloader/pearlib/download")) {
    echo "Clearing downloader/pearlib/download<br/>";
    cleandir("downloader/pearlib/download");
}

if (file_exists("downloader/pearlib/pear.ini")) {
    echo "Removing downloader/pearlib/pear.ini<br/>";
    unlink ("downloader/pearlib/pear.ini");
}

echo "<br/>************** CHECKING FOR EXTENSIONS ***********<br/>";
If (!isDirEmpty("app/code/local/")) { 
    echo "-= WARNING =- Overrides or extensions exist in the app/code/local folder<br/>";
}
If (!isDirEmpty("app/code/community/")) { 
    echo "-= WARNING =- Overrides or extensions exist in the app/code/community folder<br/>";
}
$end = (float) array_sum(explode(' ',microtime()));
echo "<br/>------------------- CLEANUP COMPLETED in:". sprintf("%.4f", ($end-$start))." seconds ------------------<br/>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `index.php` & `.htaccess` file in root directory whether the old URL is hard-coded or not. Some time we use it for redirection